# Most efficient means of using Resource Dictionaries in a large application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary

Right now in our application, which has many modules/projects in the solution, we have a specific project to hold resources called "Resource.Dictionaries", and inside that project are individual ResourceDictionary XAML files for each and every style we make.

Then, for each instance where we need one of these styles, we call it inside the resources property of the topmost parent in each view/usercontrol/data template or in c# if it's a custom control.

**In short, my question is this; does putting all of our styles and other resources in the app.xaml slow anything down** *(even if app.xaml just becomes one big merged dictionary pointing towards our remote Resource.Dictionaries)*, or is it best to continue referencing the styles/other resources ONLY where and when they're needed.

Comment: I would say yes. If the View has to look through several styles before finding the correct one then it takes more time.
Like looping through a list it takes longer if the item is way back in the list rather than knowing where the item is in the list and then just grab it.

Comment: It depends on the number of times you are retrieving data from the Resource.